# How to get distance data from the google fit Rest API for the specific activity and specific start and end time in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-fit, google-fit-api, google-fitness-api

Here, i want covered distance, when i select Date, start time, end time and any activity like "Swimming",
then i wanna get covered distance for selected date, start and end time.

I have tried to get distance from activity, but there's getting only activity duration not a distance.

Comment: Please tell us how far are you on this progress? Show some code to help us.

Comment: Till now i've implement distance api and activity.segment.
But in distance api getting only distance of whole day not a activity wise and i need with activity wise distance.